# How do I export that database in meteor

Tags: meteor

Does anyone know how I can export the application database in meteor?
I use robomongo to see it but how do I export that database? I need if you could help thanks!

Comment: Look up MongoDump. It'a related to MongoDB, not really Meteor.

Comment: Where do you want to export data, in local on on deployment? Have you deployed via mup?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Studio3T](https://studio3t.com/), it's a GUI.  You just connect it to port 3001, assuming you are using everything default.  Right click on your collection then click export.  You have different options, mongodump, csv, or json.